# CSS :after doesn't work with images?

Tags: css

I think I tried everything and `:after` simply doesn't want to work with images. Is there any CSS limitation that I'm not aware of? Or did I do something wrong?

Here's the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vHMRk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of `:after` on `img` is vaguely defined. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) puts it this way: “**Note:** Note. This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be defined in more detail in a future specification.” In practice, it’s unspecified, and there does not seem to be any progress in this are in CSS3 drafts.

Answer (score 3):

Most browsers don't support `:after` and `:before` for img tags: http://lildude.co.uk/after-css-property-for-img-tag

Comment: Weird... but okay, thanks for an answer! I'll find some other solution then.

Comment: It's not weird when you consider that `img` does not have any content that you can insert other content before or after.

Comment: Well, visually you can see that content and you can easily imagine what should happen after `:after` usage - in my opinion it should insert imaginary `DIV` just after `IMG` tag.